# Program hangs on executeBatch

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc, c3p0

I am trying to parse through a document and insert the results into a database. The document is very large (a few million records) and so I am trying to do it multithreaded with connection pooling via c3p0 and batch processing. For every 1000 records parsed, I spin off a thread that will create a PreparedStatement, insert the required series of values, and then add to that PreparedStatement's batch. However, at the executeBatch function, the program just hangs, and nothing is ever inserted into the database. I am wondering if I am using c3p0 improperly or is it something else? I've tried limiting it to the one thread thinking the multithreaded-ness might be the issue but even with just a single thread it still hangs on the execute batch.

Here's the code that spins off the thread:

```
service.submit(new ElementProcessor(source.getConnection(), fElements));
```

Source is my ComboPooledDataSource and service is an ExecutorService. Also, the constructor for the ElementProcessor class:

```
private Connection DB;
public ElementProcessor(Connection db, Element[] elements) {
    DB = db;
    try {
        DB.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
    this.elements = elements;
}
```

The stack trace from the JVM thread dump:

```
    2016-03-31 12:17:03
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b16 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" #34 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6e000000 nid=0x3e0b waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"pool-1-thread-16" #33 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b970800 nid=0x8103 waiting on condition [0x0000700002b97000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-15" #32 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6e276000 nid=0x7f03 waiting on condition [0x0000700002a94000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-14" #31 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b228800 nid=0x7d03 waiting on condition [0x0000700002991000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-13" #30 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6c0b8000 nid=0x7b03 waiting on condition [0x000070000288e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-12" #29 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b948000 nid=0x7903 waiting on condition [0x000070000278b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-11" #28 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6abf4000 nid=0x7703 waiting on condition [0x0000700002688000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-10" #27 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b1b0800 nid=0x7503 waiting on condition [0x0000700002585000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-9" #26 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6d11c800 nid=0x7303 waiting on condition [0x0000700002482000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-8" #25 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6c0fd800 nid=0x7103 waiting on condition [0x000070000237f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-7" #24 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6d9b1800 nid=0x6f03 waiting on condition [0x000070000227c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-6" #23 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6c1e8800 nid=0x6d03 waiting on condition [0x0000700002179000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-5" #22 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6e835000 nid=0x6b03 waiting on condition [0x0000700002076000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-4" #21 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6d958800 nid=0x6903 waiting on condition [0x0000700001f73000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-3" #20 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6d138000 nid=0x6703 waiting on condition [0x0000700001e70000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-2" #19 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6e189800 nid=0x6503 waiting on condition [0x0000700001d6d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-1" #18 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6c1c2800 nid=0x6303 waiting on condition [0x0000700001c6a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000772bcaca0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6d0c3000 nid=0x6103 in Object.wait() [0x0000700001b67000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000772bce798> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
    - locked <0x0000000772bce798> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rvxu59f1l0as16hejmoc|6477463f, dataSourceName->com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]-DeferredStatementDestroyerThread-#0" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6d058000 nid=0x5f03 in Object.wait() [0x0000700001a64000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000772bcecf0> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)
    - locked <0x0000000772bcecf0> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)

"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rvxu59f1l0as16hejmoc|6477463f, dataSourceName->com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]-HelperThread-#2" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6c07c800 nid=0x5d03 in Object.wait() [0x0000700001961000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000772bcf1b0> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)
    - locked <0x0000000772bcf1b0> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)

"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rvxu59f1l0as16hejmoc|6477463f, dataSourceName->com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]-HelperThread-#1" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6c07c000 nid=0x5b03 in Object.wait() [0x000070000185e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000772bcf1b0> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)
    - locked <0x0000000772bcf1b0> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)

"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rvxu59f1l0as16hejmoc|6477463f, dataSourceName->com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]-HelperThread-#0" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6c0af000 nid=0x5903 in Object.wait() [0x000070000175b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000772bcf1b0> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)
    - locked <0x0000000772bcf1b0> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)

"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2rvxu59f1l0as16hejmoc|6477463f, dataSourceName->com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]-AdminTaskTimer" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6e008000 nid=0x5707 in Object.wait() [0x0000700001658000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000772bcef08> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x0000000772bcef08> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b84b000 nid=0x5303 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b801000 nid=0x5103 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6a829800 nid=0x4f03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b028800 nid=0x4d03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b026800 nid=0x4b03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b01f800 nid=0x3a0f runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b01d800 nid=0x3803 in Object.wait() [0x0000700000d3a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000772b9a640> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
    - locked <0x0000000772b9a640> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b01c800 nid=0x3603 in Object.wait() [0x0000700000c37000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c1645268> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x00000006c1645268> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b000800 nid=0x1703 in Object.wait() [0x0000700000219000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000772c33978> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1465)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
    - locked <0x0000000772c33978> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at xmltodb.XMLToDB.endElement(XMLToDB.java:103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLNSDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(XMLNSDTDValidator.java:266)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2005)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:879)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at xmltodb.XMLToDB.main(XMLToDB.java:177)

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b01a000 nid=0x3403 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b805800 nid=0x2403 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b806000 nid=0x2603 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b806800 nid=0x2803 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b807000 nid=0x2a03 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b808000 nid=0x2c03 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b808800 nid=0x2e03 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b809000 nid=0x3003 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6b809800 nid=0x3203 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdf6c014800 nid=0x5503 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 241
```

Comment: c3p0 handles parallel batched inserts fine, in general. the first thing you should probably do to debug this is dump the JVM's thread stack and see precisely where the hang is. also, obviously, check logs for warning messages and stack traces prior. if you are using statement caching, MySQL, and c3p0, consider adding the c3p0 config param `statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads` to 1, which works around a JDBC driver fragility that can lead to freezes.

Comment: All the thread stack dumps look pretty much the same so they're definitely getting hung up on something. I've modified the original post to include the stack trace, since it doesn't fit in the comments.

Comment: Interesting update: So I turned on auto commit to see if it would make a difference and sure enough, there were 64,000 records in there before it hung. So clearly it seems like it's executing the batch inserts but then getting hung up on something else after the insertions.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I had the PreparedStatement doing closeOnCompletion() rather than plain old close() and this was causing it to hang.